# Ayuda Laravel 5.5: auth::attempt retorna falso

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un login que funcionaba perfecto con el id en su respectiva tabla, cambie la migración para que la primary fuera username (en tabla users), borrando el id, puse en el modelo la primaryKey nueva "username", pero el `auth::attempt` siempre me retorna falso y los datos se están pasando bien en el formulario.

**Modelo de User**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $primaryKey = 'username';

    public $incrementing = false;

   // protected $primary_key = 'username';

    //public $incrementing = false;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'password', 'tipo_usuario',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**LoginController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['only' => 'showLoginForm']);
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $credentials = $this->validate(request(), [
                        $this->username() => 'required|string|min:4',
                        $this->password() => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);



        if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
        {
            return $credentials;
            //return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }

        return back()
                ->withErrors([$this->username() => 'Estas credenciales no coinciden con nuestros registros'])
                ->withInput(request([$this->username()]));
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();

        return redirect('');
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }

    public function password()
    {
        return 'password';
    }
}
```

Comment: cambiaste tambien la vista auth/login.blade.php ?

Comment: cambiar qué cosa de la vista?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te sobra código. Para personalizar el campo por el que logueas solo te hace falta setearlo, con la función username el resto ( ***login(), password()*** ) lo hace Laravel

**LoginController**

```
protected $redirectTo = '/url hacia dashboard';    

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['only' => 'showLoginForm']);
}

public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('auth.login');
}   
public function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();

    return redirect('');
 }  
public function username()
{
     return 'username';
}
```